# Configure iptables to allow ddcp and SCTP

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I need help to configure the `iptables` to block everything except a few allowed computers. But they use ddcp and SCTP to communicate so I don't really know how to implement it. Here is my attempt (not working):

```
#allow all ports for ip
#udp
iptables -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
#tcp
iptables -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p tcp -j ACCEPT

#ddcp 
iptables -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p ddcp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p ddcp -j ACCEPT
#stcp 
iptables -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p SCTP -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p SCTP -j ACCEPT

#drop all
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
iptables -A OUTPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

After that, I check with `iptables -L -v -n` and a lots of packets I need were blocked. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 3):

There is clear error in your configuration. You are considering the same IP as source in both `INPUT` and `OUTPUT` chains! You may need to change it to something like:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -d 8.8.8.8/32 -p udp -j ACCEPT
```

Also, you may need to allow `RELATED`, `ESTABLISHED` traffic in addition to loopback traffic via `lo` interface for locally running applications.

```
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: Hi, I dont have access to the bash file right now so I write what I remember :) Thank for the headup. Do you have any ideas about those protocols allowance? Because I think if the `iptables` up before the program start, it could block the needed packets as well.

Comment: @Tiana987642: It will be better to use `iptables-restore` and `iptables-save`  in this case.